# PHP intl extension not loading after enabling it

Tags: php

Just when I tried to use the NumberFormatter class in my code which requires the php intl extension in order to use the class. I enabled the extension by un-commenting it in the php.ini configuration file but still won't work. I changed this

```
;extension=intl
```

to this

```
extension=intl
```

but still doesn't work even after restarting my server.

Comment: Have you checked if it is recognized as installed php extension? 
Try `php -m` in a shell or take a look at the output of `phpinfo();`. Check if it is listed there.

Comment: I solved the issue, check my answer below. Any person that the answer didn't solve his problem means the `php_intl.dll` file is missing in their extension directory

Comment: Install php-intl extension using  "sudo apt-get install php-intl"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way to do that which works for me. What I did is to copy the all the files containing this name `icu****.dll` from my php directory into the Apache `bin` directory then restart my server.

The `icu****.dll` files are up to 4 in my own php directory. I tried this using php version 7.4.9

To see the loaded extensions, run the code below on your server.

```
<?php
$extensions = get_loaded_extensions();
print_r($extensions);
?>
```

The solution was got from this [github issue](https://github.com/easyphp/easyphp-devserver/issues/25)